# Find any sequence that meets these criteria.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinity, divergent-series

I'm struggling with this problem and don't know where to start looking:

Is there any sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}) \neq \infty$?

If so, which one? If not, why not?

Can anyone help me out?

*EDIT*: Also, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the edited question: suppose that $a_n \to L \not= 0$. Then $|a_n| \to |L|$, but since $|L|^{1/n} \to 1$ you get $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \to 1$, so $n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \to \infty$.

---

How about $0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots$?

Comment: I'm not sure if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}) \neq \infty$ holds here. Wouldn't the factor of $n$ destroy it?

Comment: Every other term is zero. The sequence reads $0,2,0,4,0,8,\ldots$

Comment: Here the limit conditions are satisfied, since neither limit exists.

Comment: Oops, how clumsy. You're right, thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited the question since this idea is neat, but not what I meant to ask for. I actually need the first limit to converge to anything but 0 or ∞.

Comment: About your edit: Now, this definitely breaks the claim that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}) \neq \infty$. :)

EDIT: Whoops again, I didn't realize that you disproved the existence. Thanks again!

Comment: Correct. No sequence satisfies the conditions you propose.

Answer (score 0):

Umberto has a good answer for the case where $a_n$ is not taken to converge. If the second limit does converge, say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}( n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}) = C$$ then $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ is approximately $C/n$ for large $n$.